# Wordpress: index.php vs home.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im reading this tutorial [Wordpress theming](http://www.charityandbiscuits.com/blog/tutorial-convert-bootstrap-site-template-wordpress/) about converting an html site to WP, and it says

> WordPress has a hierarchy of templates. None of them are called index
>   (that name is reserved) so we need to rename our index file to
>   something else.

So as per tutorial I renamed index.html to home.php. But when I go to themes it says that the theme is broken as it is missing a template and it shows as a valid theme only when I rename home.php to index.php.

Should I use index.php or keep home.php and it will recognize it after I have other pages like header.php etc?

ps. Tutorial is outdated?

Comment: if you have a chance to update the tutorial, then do it.

Comment: you can use index.php no problems. I had a quick look at that tutorial and it will give you the basics but research creating new templates for pages and it will be a bit clearer to you (you can select a template for pages by default wp will recognise files called page-CUSTOMNAME.php as template files (you need to note the name within comments in the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates):

> At the very minimum, a WordPress Theme consists of two files:
>   style.css
>   index.php

you need to keep the index.php file.
home.php is also uses by wordpress template already as an option for [front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) as the website home page instead of default blog page - index.php.

> home.php
> The home page template, which is the front page by default.
>   If you use a static front page this is the template for the page with
>   the latest posts.

if you want to create a new template for home, you can for example create a new php file for [new custom template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) and put the "template name" in the start of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: my template
*/
```

then set the page called 'home' to your new template from the admin panel.